# Django form ModelMultipleChoiceField with 10K options

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a filed called `location` on my form and I don't need to pre-load all the options as it takes a long time to render. So this is what I have:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    location = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        label='Location',
        queryset=Location.objects.none()
    )
```

And I've provided an autocomplete feature using ajax. The issue is the form validation fails as the selected values are not in the `queryset`. Is there a way I can skip `location`'s validation or something similar to that?

Edit:

I found a way but I don't think it's the best option:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
location = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    required=False,
    label='Location',
    validators=[]
)
```

I added `validators = []` to my location field and changed `ModelMultipleChoiceField` to `MultipleChoiceField`. Now, in my `save` function, I have this:

```
def save(self):
    if not self.is_valid():
        return false

    locations = Location.objects.filter(id__in=self.data.getlist('location')).all()
```

As `locations` won't be in my `cleaned_data`, I just query the database using the location ids passed in `data`.

I still don't think this is a clean way, so any other solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you may can use django-autocomplete-light library for Django.

This library is very easier for the use and the load is through of Ajax calls.

here is the link for complete details

[django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. But I wanted to find a way to fix it without any external plugin.